# How to create a excel spreadsheet of indeterminate length with dataframe?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

I am a bit of a new user to python and I have been writing a program where I need to create an excel spreadsheet with an indeterminate number of columns. So my previous code to create exactly 4 columns was:

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(datapath + 'Test#' + str(testcount) + '.xlsx', engine = 'xlsxwriter')
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Species 1' : evolution[0]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Species 2' : evolution[1]})
df3 = pd.DataFrame({'Species 3' : evolution[2]})
df4 = pd.DataFrame({'Species 4' : evolution[3]})
df1.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Raw Data')
df2.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Raw Data', startcol=2, index=False)
df3.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Raw Data', startcol=3, index=False)
df4.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Raw Data', startcol=4, index=False)
writer.save()
```

(Evolution is a separate function from which I draw the data to populate the columns.) So the above code worked exactly as needed. My attempt at creating a way to have an indeterminate number of columns was this:

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(datapath + 'Test#' + str(testcount) + '.xlsx', engine = 'xlsxwriter')
def do(x):
    and1 = x+1
    "df" + str(and1) = pd.DataFrame({"Species " + str(i) : evolution[x]})
def do2(x):
    and1 = x+1
    "df" + str(and1).to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Raw Data', startcol=and1, index=False)
def repeat(times, f):
    for i in range(times): f()

repeat(colnumb, do)
repeat(colnumb, do2)
writer.save()
```

("colnumb" is a predefined variable.) However, this keeps on outputting the following error:

```
"df" + str(and1) = pd.DataFrame({"Species " + str(i) : evolution[x]})
^
SyntaxError: can't assign to operator
```

If someone could help me see what is wrong with my attempted solutions or clarify a better way to accomplish my goal I would be very grateful. (Also sorry if I messed up any formatting. This is my first time posting a question here so if I did mess up some convention please let me know.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have over-engineered this. The syntax error you are getting is because you are trying to create dynamic variable names to store each dataframe, but you cannot store a value in an expression (i.e. `str(and1)` cannot hold the value returned by `pd.DataFrame({"Species " + str(i) : evolution[x-1]})`. Thankfully, this operation is unnecessary, so let's look at the rest of the code.

First, you can combine all your functions into a single iteration so that you only iterate over your columns once, and then perform all the necessary operations for that column. This is best performed by a dict comprehension. Second, it looks like you are currently using DataFrames to hold Series objects. You can actually create your entire dataframe first before exporting it, in full, to Excel.

You call the `colnumb` variable in your repeat() calls, but I am not sure where it comes from, since you have not created any dataframes with columns yet. Is it the length of `evolution`? Also, you call `evolution` a function, but interact with it like a list that is storing results of a previously run function. I'll provide solutions for both scenarios. A much simpler and more efficient version would look like:

1. If `colnumb` is some arbitrary number you input

   ```
   # Create a dictionary with all columns of dynamic Species names storing the relevant value of evolution.
   species_dict = {'Species {}'.format(i) : [evolution[i]] for i in range(colnumb)}

   # Turn that dict into a dataframe
   df = pd.DataFrame(species_dict)

   # Output the dataframe to Excel
   df.to_excel(datapath + 'Test#' + str(testcount) + 'xlsx', 'Raw Data')
   ```
2. And if `colnumb` is really just the length of evolution:

   ```
   # Create dict by enumerating all values of evolution to access both index and value
   species_dict = {'Species {}'.format(i): [value] for i, value in evolution.items()}

   # Convert dict to dataframe
   df = pd.DataFrame(species_dict)

   # Output the dataframe to Excel
   df.to_excel(datapath + 'Test#' + str(testcount) + 'xlsx', 'Raw Data')
   ```

Comment: Thanks for your response! I can see how the value of colnumb could be confusing but I intended it as just an arbitrary value that I input. However, when I tried out the recommended code I ran into the following error: "TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable". I was wondering if there was a way around that?

Comment: Can you show me what code you ran that generated that error? This works perfectly for me.

And again, what type of object is `evolution`?

Comment: Yeah what I ran was: writer = pd.ExcelWriter(datapath + 'Test#' + str(testcount) + '.xlsx', engine = 'xlsxwriter')
        species_dict = {'Species {}'.format(i) : [evolution(i)] for i in range(colnumb)}
        df = pd.DataFrame(species_dict)
        df.to_excel(datapath + 'Test#' + str(testcount) + 'xlsx', 'Raw Data')
        writer.save()

Comment: You also might consider whether your ideal output is a single row with a bunch of columns, or if a more clear data structure would be a dataframe with "Species" and "Evolution Value" as columns, and then the species numbers and `evolution` results in their respective columns. I will edit my response to show that possibility.

Comment: Is there a reason you are defining a pd.ExcelWriter as opposed to simply using `df.to_excel(<filename>, <sheetname>)`?

Comment: Oh, I see the issue - `enumerate` is indeed a dict, and not a function as you said, so the code should be `species_dict = {'Species {}'.format(i) : [evolution[i]] for i in range(colnumb)}`. I updated my response to reflect that.

Comment: Great! Thanks for the check.

Answer (score 1):

You can create just one dataframe with all columns and export it :

```
data = {'Species 1' : evolution[0], 'Species 2' : evolution[1], 'Species 3' : evolution[2], 'Species 4' : evolution[3]}

writer = pd.ExcelWriter(datapath + 'Test#' + str(testcount) + '.xlsx', engine = 'xlsxwriter')
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Raw Data')
writer.save()
```

It's your question ?

Comment: Thanks for the response! Your idea would really help me make my code more compact. However, I want to be able to create any number of columns, not just four. So, essentially, I want to be able to input any given value (ie. 7) and have the program create said number of columns automatically. However, your suggestion does give me the idea to perhaps use a "for _ in range _ " loop to create a dict with the data for the number of columns I want and then pass that to pd.DataFrame. So I will try that out and tell you what happens.

Comment: So I tried out my idea based on your suggestions but I ran into the same error. For reference this is the code I tried to replace the first half of my previous code with:                                                                   dlist = {}
for i in range(1, colnumb + 1):
     dlist['Species' +str(i)] = [evolution[i-1]]                                              for i in range(1, colnumb + 1):
    "df" + str(i) = pd.DataFrame(dlist['Species' + str(i)])

Comment: I actually made a small error in that previous attempt because I passed pd.DataFrame the argument --> dlist['Species' +str(i)] instead of the whole set of dlist. But when I replaced that and passed pd.DataFrame(dlist) by itself I ran into the same problem once again.

Comment: you can't attributate value to a function like  "df" + str(i), you need to create automatically the dictionnary like :
    dlist = {}
    for i in range(1, 10):
        dlist.setdefault('species %i' % i, range(i))